# Cannot import goto in sveltekit

Tags: routes, sveltekit, goto

I am using a brand new installation of sveltekit "svelte": "^3.54.0", When I try to import goto with this code

```js
import { goto } from "$app/navigation";
```

I get the following typescript error

> Cannot find module '$app/navigation' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

I have nuked the node_modules and that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

it would be best if you guarded your goto with an if statement and make sure the if statement checks for the browser env variable. Try this code:

```
<script>
import {browser} from '$app/environment';
import {goto} from '$app/navigation';

$: {
   if(browser && SOME OTHER CONDITION){
   RUN YOUR CODE E.G: goto('/route')
   }
}

</script>
```

If you're not satisfied with this, then check out this [ISSUE](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/3245) raised on GitHub, it worked for me: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/3245

Answer (score 0):

Those types are in the SvelteKit package `@sveltejs/kit`, specifically in `@sveltejs/kit/types/ambient.d.ts`. The types should be picked up automatically if the package is installed, as far as I know.

The `tsconfig.json` setup might also matter, it should have an `extends` entry:

```json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    ...
}
```

Possibly run `svelte-kit sync` or start the dev server to make it setup the `.svelte-kit` directory.

Comment: yes my tsconfig.json does have that entry. The code runs its just the typescript error that I cannot get rid of

Comment: Might be an editor issue then.

Comment: I am using vscode

Comment: If I run npm run "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json" I get the error too